# Suppress Blank Space between two line of Text in PHPWord

Tags: codeigniter, phpword

I'm attempting to create word file using **PHPWord**. I have set some font styles and paragraph styles.Even without giving textbreaks i am getting 6 lines of **blank spaces** between line1 and line2. Any advice?

Here is my code

```
    $this->word->addFontStyle('titleStyle', array('bold' => true, 'size' => 16, 'name'=>'Calibri'));
    $this->word->addFontStyle('lineStyle', array('align'=>'left','size' => 10, 'name'=>'Calibri'));
    $this->word->addParagraphStyle('pStyle', array('align' => 'center', 'spaceBefore' => 0, 'spaceAfter' => 0, 'spacing' => 0));

    $section = $this->word->createSection(array('breakType'=>'continuous'));

    // Simple text
    $section->addText('Text Document','titleStyle','pStyle');

    $section->addText('Line1 : ','lineStyle');      
    $section->addText('Line2 : ','lineStyle');      
    $section->addText('Line3 : ','lineStyle');          
    $section->addText('Line4 : ','lineStyle');          


    $filename='NewDoc.docx'; //save our document as this file name
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

    $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($this->word, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

any help will be appreciated.

Below is my output file which is being generated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your defined paragraph styles are not applied to any of the added text.

If you want to apply your defined paragraph style to the added text, you need to add the name (or definition) as a parameter:

```
$section->addText('Line 1 : '.$line1,'lineStyle', 'pStyle');
```

or if you prefer to create global paragraph style that will be automatically used everywhere:

```
$phpWord->setDefaultParagraphStyle(array('align'=>'left','size' => 10, 'name'=>'Calibri'));
```

Comment: The piece of code in your question (when replacing the $line1 etc with some constant strings) did not create any additional spaces or lines for me. Do you have something in your variables that might be causing the extra lines?

Comment: Well, now i have removed all the variable and using simple constant strings like how u have tried. but i am still getting the same problem. i have updated my code on top. May be i am using different version of PHPWord than you. i downloaded one from gitHUb.

Comment: yep, I'm using 0.12.0 which isn't the latest - so if you are using the 0.13.0 version there might be some differences...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. i am not using github, rather i am using codeplex PHPWord. https://phpword.codeplex.com/

Comment: is there any way i can have the link of the source which you are currently using.(GitHub)

Comment: ah, the codeplex is an old and inactive project. The latest & maintained version is available at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord